# Java Generics with Enum value inserted?

Tags: java, generics, enums, quartz-scheduler

I have an `enum`, e.g.

```
public enum TimerCommandType {
   DATAPUBLISH,
   CLEARCACHE
}
```

and I want to be able to generate a class using Generics, so it looks like:

```
TimerCommandClass<DATAPUBLISH>
```

which will use the `enum` value inside the class when relevant.

**Is this possible?**

The reason I would like to have it is that I currently have many calls to Quartz Jobs like:

```
 public JobDetailFactoryBean publishingJobDetail() {
    return QuartzSchedulerHelper.createJobDetail(QuartzPublishingJob.class);
}
```

and I want them to be replaced to:

```
QuartzSchedulerHelper.createJobDetail(TimerCommandClass<DATAPUBLISH>.class);
```

where `createJobDetail` is simply:

```
static JobDetailFactoryBean createJobDetail(Class jobClass) {
    JobDetailFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJobClass(jobClass);
    return factoryBean;
}
```

Comment: Generic types are types. `DATAPUBLISH` is not a type; it's an instance of `TimerCommandType`.

Comment: "A generic type is a generic class or interface that is parameterized over types"

As stated in the javadoc

Thus DATAPUBLISH will not work as you stated above.

Comment: Why don't you simply define `class DataPublish` and `class ClearCache`?

Comment: Why do you think that you need generics in your case ? Do you have a method that returns a `TimeCommandType` or takes a `TimeCommandType` as argument ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DATAPUBLISH` is a value, not a type, so it can not be used as a type parameter.

Even if it was possible, type parameters are erased at runtime, so `TimerCommandClass<DATAPUBLISH>.class` would be the same as `TimerCommandClass.class`.

Answer (score 0):

`TimerCommandClass<DATAPUBLISH>` this doesn't make sense it should be parametrized with the class so in our case TimerCommandType not with the instance of the class DATAPUBLISH. To pass the instance you can use the methods or constructor parameters.